# AngularJS Directive Create OnTheFly Textbox and Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, textbox

In a directive, I am creating a textbox on-the-fly and the validation along with it.

The texbox is being created correctly and works.

See plnker:
  https://plnkr.co/edit/YJIwS8bD0w5e9LbWBtlJ?p=preview

BUT the error div ng-show is not being generated corretly from the directive's propErrPattern: '=' AND propErrReqr: '='.

I have tried at least a dozen ways but nothing works.  The template is generating:

```
<p class="error" ng-show="propErrPattern || propErrReqr">
    <b class="ng-binding">Required. Length:-  Characters:</b> Letters, Numbers, Dash, Underscore, Space
</p>

<!-- instead of generating   -->
<!-- instead of generating   -->
<p class="error" ng-show="FirstName.$error.pattern || irstName.$error.required">


app.directive('textBox', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            label: '@label',
            value: '@value',
            property: '=',
            propErrPattern: '=',
            propErrReqr: '=',
            lenMin: '@lenMin',
            lenMax: '@lenMax',
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'textboxTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

In a form I call the directive by:

```
<text-box 
    label="First Name" 
    value="FirstName" 
    property='FirstName' 
    propErrPattern='FirstName.$error.pattern' 
    propErrReqr='FirstName.$error.required' 
    lenMin='3' 
    lenMax='15'>
</text-box>
```

The textboxTemplate.html (notice ng-show="propErrPattern || propErrReqr")

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{value}}" class="control-label col-sm-4">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="{{value}}"
               name="{{value}}"
               ng-model="property"
               ng-pattern="/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i" 
               ng-minlength="{{lenMin}}"
               ng-maxlength="{{lenMax}}"
               ng-trim="true"
               required />
        <!-- NOT GENERATING CORRECTLY -->
        <!-- NOT GENERATING CORRECTLY -->
        <p class="error" ng-show="propErrPattern || propErrReqr" >
            <b>Required. Length:{{lenMin}}-{{lenMax}}  Characters:</b> Letters, Numbers, Dash, Underscore, Space
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a number of things wrong with your implementation.  Your use of the directive should look like this.

```
<text-Box label="First Name" value="FirstName" property='FirstName' 
prop-err-pattern='myForm.FirstName.$error.pattern' 
prop-err-reqr='myForm.FirstName.$error.required' lenMin='3' lenMax='15'>
</text-Box>
```

Notice that the properties that are camel case in your directive should are set via a dashed '-' name.  That is propErrPattern becomes prop-err-pattern.
next note that your values for propErrPattern and propErrReqr should start with the name of your form, in this case 'myForm'.

Those two changes should make things work properly.

Comment: That did it !  Thanks because I have spent hours researching this.